# What is the proper code style for relative imports in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and Dart. How should I import files found on the same folder and those from other folders? Is it proper to use ../ or should I write with the package url?

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:my_app/core/widgets/menus.dart' show SidebarMenu;
import './settings.dart' show SettingsScreen;

class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  DashboardScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  static const String routeName = '/dashboard';

  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: landscape(),
    );
  }

  Widget landscape() {
    return new SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new SidebarMenu(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dart style guide [recommends using relative imports](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-relative-paths-when-importing-libraries-within-your-own-packages-lib-directory).

It has the advantage of staying correct even if you rename your package (which is admittedly rare). It's also short and makes it very clear to the reader that this is a library in the same package.

There have been issues when libraries inside the `lib/` directory of a package are referenced using a file path. Currently, if your entry point is in the `lib/` dir, which Flutter uses, the Dart compiler *will* recognize that and change the entry point URI to a `package:` URI. That avoids most of the issues that was attempted fixed by using full `package:` URIs. You should still not refer to a file inside the `lib/` directory with a path containing `lib/` in any other place (like from the `bin/` or `test/` directories of the pub package).

Comment: I never knew that there was such a rule. It will be necessary to apply it.

Comment: So is it okay if I use the ../ to escape a couple directories to get to another one given that both the source and the destination paths are inside the lib/ directory?

Comment: So if I import menus.dart inside dashboard.dart, I do something like this? 
import '../../../../core/widgets/menus.dart' as Menus;

Comment: As long as all the intermediate paths stay inside `lib`, there should be no problem. If the URI is `package:foo/some/path/lib.dart` then using `../../../lib/other/lib.dart` won't work because you have to stay inside the `package:` URI path.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the [Flutter Boring Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yr8F2S3Amas&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIK0r_D-zWcmJ1plIcDNnRkK) on youtube (sorry, cannot remember the episode, they mention the existence of a bug where use of the relative path (../) can cause issues when used in combination with the package path.

While this bug may have been resolved, they do mention a few times that the package url is the preferred style.